# Caching Objects in Android Internal Storage

Tags: java, android

i am storing data in internal storage

```
public static void writeObject(Context context, String key, Object object) throws IOException {
  FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(object);
  oos.close();
  fos.close();
```

}

but  can i see this saved data on phone if yes path please ? any way i can store where user can't see this

Comment: If you have a rooted device you can see it under `/data/data/your.package.name/`. On a non-rooted device, it is also in that folder, but you do not have permissions to see it from shell

Comment: any way i can stop it ?

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by 'stop it'

Comment: how i can stop user to see this ?

Comment: basically  that data is imp so any way i can decrypt it ?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent your user from seeing it. You can't stop the user from rooting his device from your app. You could let your filename start  with a dot, `.your_data_file` for example, so it is a hidden file, but it will still be there

Comment: If you have sensitive data, the best thing you can do is store it somewhere that is not on your device i.e. a server

Comment: no i can't store on server , i can make encryption and save it can ayn five good way to do it

Answer (score 0):

you can store the image in the Cache storage , it will be private, only from your application users can see the images

```
public static String saveToCacheMemory(Activity activity, Bitmap 

bitmapImage){

    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(activity);
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,mDateFormat.format(new Date())  + StaticVariables.imageFormat);

    Log.d(TAG, "directory: " + directory);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        Log.d(TAG, "bit exception: Success" );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "bit exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "io exce: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "absolute path " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
    return mypath.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

if you have [more doubts check my blog post](https://cjdevelops.blogspot.com/2021/09/save-files-images-videos-in-internal.html)